# Does s take 3 bytes in Java? when : String s = "abc"; Java

Tags: java, memory, compiler-construction, jvm

If I write this in Java:

```
String s = "abc";
```

Does s only occupy 3 bytes in the memory?
If true, how JVM finds the end of the String object?
Does this take more bytes in memory?

Comment: Read the source for the `String` class.

Comment: If you read the source for the String class you will see it stores the length which is how it knows how long the string is. BTW "abc" uses about 48 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes more than 3 bytes, read on for full explanation from [this page](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml)

> For reasons we'll explore below, the minimum memory usage of a Java
>   String (in the Hotspot Java 6 VM) is generally as follows:
>
> ```
> Minimum String memory usage (bytes) = 8 * (int) ((((no chars) * 2) + 45) / 8)
> ```
>
> Or, put another way:
>
> - multiply the number of characters of the String by two;
> - add 38;
> - if the result is not a multiple of 8, round up to the next multiple    of 8;
> - the result is generally the minimum number of bytes taken up on the    heap by the String.

[This page](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_saving_memory.shtml) from the same website also details ways in which you can save memory using classes different than `String`

Comment: Add 38.  The 45 is to round up instead of down.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, not by a long shot.  JVM strings are well-known for being quite heavy; the object contains not only a pointer to the character array but also its length.  And the internal storage use UTF-16 codepoints, so your question could have been "does it take 6 bytes?" :-)

A technical reference to the JVM will give you the exact size of string objects.  You can also find some interesting blog posts [such as this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702032839/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2010/06/22/the-unbearable-heaviness-jav-strings/) and technical articles.

There is a good deal more to the question of the exact size of string objects.  We can get in to compression of object pointers, string interning, etc.  There is also the fact that since strings are immutable, we often have sharing of string memory, as happens when you call `substring` for example.

However, what is always true is: it's more than 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum String memory usage (bytes) = 8 * (int) ((((num of chars) * 2) + 45) / 8)

Comment: in theory it could be less than that ... if you take into account Strings that share backing arrays.

Comment: That's something else, OP is asking about memory usage and a single string.